# Identifying patterns in two strings in R

Tags: r, split, string-matching

I want to evaluate if ColA contains a new string than ColB. However, I am not interested in certain types of string, for example, **oil**. I would like to have an indicator variable as follow:

```
  ColA                           ColB                       Ind
--------------------------      ------------------------   -----
 coconut+grape+pine              grape+coconut              TRUE
 orange+apple+grape+pine         grape+coconut              TRUE
 grape+pine                      grape+oil                  TRUE
 oil+grape                       grape+apple                FALSE
 grape                           grape+oil                  FALSE
 grape+pine                      grape+orange+pine          FALSE
```

Any Suggestions using R?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we need to split the strings, we'll start with `strsplit`,

```r
strsplit(dat$ColA, '+', fixed = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "coconut" "grape"   "pine"   
# [[2]]
# [1] "orange" "apple"  "grape"  "pine"  
# [[3]]
# [1] "grape" "pine" 
# [[4]]
# [1] "oil"   "grape"
# [[5]]
# [1] "grape"
# [[6]]
# [1] "grape" "pine"
```

From here, we want to determine what is in `ColA` that is not in `ColB`. I'll use `Map` to run `setdiff` on each set (`ColA`'s `[[1]]` with `ColB`'s `[[1]]`, etc).

```r
Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat$ColA, '+', fixed = TRUE), strsplit(dat$ColB, '+', fixed = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "pine"
# [[2]]
# [1] "orange" "apple"  "pine"  
# [[3]]
# [1] "pine"
# [[4]]
# [1] "oil"
# [[5]]
# character(0)
# [[6]]
# character(0)
```

To determine which one has "new words", we can just check for non-zero length using `lengths(.) > 0`:

```r
lengths(Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat$ColA, '+', fixed = TRUE), strsplit(dat$ColB, '+', fixed = TRUE))) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But since you don't care about `oil`, we need to remove that as well.

```r
lapply(Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat$ColA, '+', fixed = TRUE), strsplit(dat$ColB, '+', fixed = TRUE)), setdiff, "oil")
# [[1]]
# [1] "pine"
# [[2]]
# [1] "orange" "apple"  "pine"  
# [[3]]
# [1] "pine"
# [[4]]
# character(0)
# [[5]]
# character(0)
# [[6]]
# character(0)
lengths(lapply(Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat$ColA, '+', fixed = TRUE), strsplit(dat$ColB, '+', fixed = TRUE)),
               setdiff, "oil")) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

@akrun suggested a tidyverse variant:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)   # map2_lgl
library(stringr) # str_extract_all
dat %>%
  mutate(
    new = map2_lgl(
      str_extract_all(ColB, "\\w+"), str_extract_all(ColA, "\\w+"),
      ~ !all(setdiff(.y, "oil") %in% .x)
    )
  )
#                      ColA              ColB   Ind   new
# 1      coconut+grape+pine     grape+coconut  TRUE  TRUE
# 2 orange+apple+grape+pine     grape+coconut  TRUE  TRUE
# 3              grape+pine         grape+oil  TRUE  TRUE
# 4               oil+grape       grape+apple FALSE FALSE
# 5                   grape         grape+oil FALSE FALSE
# 6              grape+pine grape+orange+pine FALSE FALSE
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ColA = c("coconut+grape+pine", "orange+apple+grape+pine", "grape+pine", "oil+grape", "grape", "grape+pine"), ColB = c("grape+coconut", "grape+coconut", "grape+oil", "grape+apple", "grape+oil", "grape+orange+pine"), Ind = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: A tidyverse option is `df1 %>% mutate(new = map2_lgl(str_extract_all(ColB, "\\w+"), str_extract_all(ColA, "\\w+"), ~ !all(setdiff(.y, "oil") %in% .x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution similar to [r2evans's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361069/6574038) that calls `strsplit` only once with the help of `do.call`.

```
rid <- function(x) x[!x %in% z]  ## helper FUN to get rid of the oil

z <- "oil"
L <- sapply(unname(dat), strsplit, "\\+")
dat$ind <- sapply(1:nrow(L), function(x) length(do.call(setdiff, rev(Map(rid, L[x,]))))) > 0
dat
#                  V1                      V2   ind
# 1     grape+coconut      coconut+grape+pine  TRUE
# 2     grape+coconut orange+apple+grape+pine  TRUE
# 3         grape+oil              grape+pine  TRUE
# 4       grape+apple               oil+grape FALSE
# 5         grape+oil                   grape FALSE
# 6 grape+orange+pine              grape+pine FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("grape+coconut", "grape+coconut", "grape+oil", 
"grape+apple", "grape+oil", "grape+orange+pine"), V2 = c("coconut+grape+pine", 
"orange+apple+grape+pine", "grape+pine", "oil+grape", "grape", 
"grape+pine")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```